# can we call some part of native in HTML

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed native ios carousal and some graph page which is in native. I have common header and footer for my application which i want throughout the application.

Now the problem is if i call native page using `WL.nativePage.show()` for carousal which will show the carousal part but what about common header footer that can only be achieved by making header footer in native code also.

But i don't want like this , i want that carousal part into my Html so that header footer remain same and carousal comes in between.

Or is there some customization in worklight for doing that. At last i want my header footer common throughout the application. How would i achieve it.

Comment: Please describe more your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_06_Integrating_server_generated_pages_in_Worklight_applications.pdf) in the Worklight Getting Started materials that shows how to add a WebView overlay to a hybrid app.  The presentation materials focus on Android, but the associated sample has both Android and iOS.  I would think the same technique could be used to add your carousel as an overlay